# Is fail2ban working?

Tags: fail2ban

I recently installed 2 new servers with Centos 7. I have enabled fail2ban with defaults. I have ensured it is running as ps -ax | grep fail2ban yields:

```
1996 ?        S      0:04 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/fail2ban-server -b -s /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock -p /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid -x
```

But my nightly logs look like this:

```
sshd:
  Authentication Failures:
   root (60.173.26.165): 1070 Time(s)
   root (122.225.109.208): 515 Time(s)
   root (193.106.4.48): 391 Time(s)
   root (122.225.109.104): 297 Time(s)
   root (122.225.109.213): 286 Time(s)
   root (122.225.109.219): 248 Time(s)
   root (122.225.109.199): 220 Time(s)
   root (113.200.114.230): 199 Time(s)
   unknown (122.225.109.208): 140 Time(s)
   root (122.225.109.204): 133 Time(s)
   root (122.225.97.73): 131 Time(s)
   root (122.225.97.70): 119 Time(s)
   root (122.225.109.196): 99 Time(s)
   root (61.174.50.134): 87 Time(s)
   unknown (122.225.109.213): 67 Time(s)
   root (122.225.97.98): 66 Time(s)
   root (61.174.51.222): 65 Time(s)
   unknown (122.225.109.104): 65 Time(s)
   root (122.225.109.203): 64 Time(s)
   unknown (122.225.109.199): 57 Time(s)
   unknown (122.225.109.204): 18 Time(s)
   unknown (122.225.109.196): 16 Time(s)
   root (61.234.104.167): 8 Time(s)
   root (80.191.81.53): 1 Time(s)
   unknown (113.200.114.230): 1 Time(s)
   unknown (122.225.109.219): 1 Time(s)
   unknown (193.106.4.48): 1 Time(s)
   unknown (91.220.131.33): 1 Time(s)
```

When I used to run denyhosts, I neve rsaw more than 2 or 3 attempts then that IP got banned. Does this result tell me that fail2ban is not configured correctly?

EDIT ( suggested by sebix )

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/auth.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex file : /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf
Use         maxlines : 10
Use      single line : /var/log/auth.log


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:

Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 1 missed
|- Missed line(s):
|  /var/log/auth.log
```

Comment: I'm also seeing fail2ban not actually banning anything on CentOS 7. I haven't had time to chase it down yet, though.

Comment: What does `fail2ban-regex` show with your config and log show for the night and what happens when you change your backend (gamin/polling)?

Comment: I have no idea what any of that means sebix.

Comment: @DougWolfgram Did you make sure `findtime` is correct in `jail.conf` ?

Comment: Is this good??

bantime  = 3600
findtime  = 600
maxretry = 3

Comment: Does /var/log/auth.log exist on Centos? Type: `fail2ban-client status` to find out which jails are loaded. If your jail for ssh is called _ssh-iptables_ type: `fail2ban-client status ssh-iptables` this should show what log the jail is reading from.

Comment: THis doesn't look good...

[root@csdev log]# fail2ban-client status
Status
|- Number of jail: 0
`- Jail list: 

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. is your system using firewall-cmd? if so did you set fail2ban to firewallcmd-ipset?  2. do you have a auth.log my centos 7 has no auth.log.

Comment: I am not using firewall. I did finally get it to work. There is another config file you need when using iptables

Comment: Are still having the issue ? It seems that sshd jail is note enabled give us a link to your jail.conf in order to help. I have resolved your issue please update this question. Thanks.